# how do i mount this old Toyo Toki (Toto) sink?

Tags: plumbing, sink

I'd like to use this small sink in a powder room, but can't figure out how it mounts to the wall. There are large holes for lugs at the bottom, but if that's it the sink will tip and crack.

Does something go into the two upper holes? I've looked for brackets and nothing matches; they all use a French cleat system. I haven't found a guide to installing an old wall mount sink either; everything I found says "now install the bracket supplied by the manufacturer". Doh!

Edit: I understand that something is going to have to go into the top holes to secure the sink. I just don't understand what or how. The two top holes go into the sink and I have no access to the front. So I can't insert a screw or bolt there to stick out the back.

Any suggestions?

Edit 2: Added a couple more pictures of the back of the sink. I think making a cleat-type bracket like @eric-poole suggested just might work!

[image: backside of sink]
[image: detail of identifying marks]
[image: Underside of sink - lip for bracket]
[image: underside of sink 2]

Comment: The top holes in the corners are the ones you definitely want to attach with at least.

Comment: That makes the most sense to me. The question is, how? The holes go inside the sink; I have no access to the front of those holes. so I can't insert a screw or bolt into the front.

Comment: Hooks might do it. L-hooks, more specifically - probably L-hooks with the bent part shorter than how they typically are made (easy enough to modify in that direction, at least.) Straight bolts or pins at an angle might also work. Or there might be a bracket (or much larger hooks) that's supposed to grab the middle of the sink (above the logo but forward of the back surface, yet behind the bowl) more pictures from different angles might show traces of that, or that that is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two top holes in the corners are there because the sink is hollow. They are from the making of the sink. You will not use those holes. Every wall mounted sink that I have installed uses a [bracket](https://www.google.com/search?q=lavatory%20sink%20bracket&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) that is mounted on the wall first into at least one stud, then the sink drops down onto the bracket. The two lower holes then would probably line up to two holes on the bracket so the sink cannot be accidentally moved or bumped off the bracket.

If you do not have the bracket, you may have to fabricate one (I would use wood). It should not get wet back there if you caulk along the top of the sink after installation, so the wood should not fall apart over time.

Comment: I looked at the back of the sink again based on this answer. It looks like the ledge is about 45 degrees so it probably accepts a bracket like @eric-poole says. If I can't use a prefab steel bracket (or can't find one) then I can just cut a notch out of a 2x4 or 1x3 to hold it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just off the top of my head, but that sink looks like it is the top of a toilet tank.  All of our old toilet tanks ( I live near Tokyo) have a faucet that shoots out water when the toilet is flushed so we can wash our hands in bathrooms with no sink.  If that is he case, I think you would have trouble mounting the ‘sink” so it was freestanding.